# Ramsey's theorem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ramsey-theory

For $k=2$, from this post [A "geometrical" representation for Ramsey's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4584/a-geometrical-representation-for-ramseys-theorem), how one can deduce the theorem from [Constant $f:[\mathbb{N}]^2\to \{1,2\}$ (part 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237949/constant-f-mathbbn2-to-1-2-part-2), or by knowing that there exist infinite sequence of naturals $n_1,n_2,n_3,...$, and a sequence of $t_1,t_2,t_3,...$ where $t_n\in\{1,2\}$ for all $n$, and if $i<j$, then $f(\{n_i,n_j\})=t_i$.

How to represent set $H$ (set $H$ is from the first link)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re practically done at this point.

Let $N_1=\{n_k:t_k=1\}$ and $N_2=\{n_k:t_k=2\}$. At least one of these sets must be infinite, so without loss of generality assume that $N_1$ is infinite; then $f(\{n_i,n_k\})=1$ for all $\{n_i,n_k\}\in[N_1]^2$.